# Can one apply LHopitals' rule to differentiable functions defined over the naturals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

For e.g, if we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(n)}{g(n)}$= $\frac 00$, $f:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ and $g:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ (note that $f$,$g$ are defined on $R$ so the derivative makes sense)  so in essence, we're considering sequences.

Comment: I've done most of it, but I can't get R to show up as the real number line

Comment: Yes, you can. If $$\lim_{x \in \mathbb{R}, x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ exists as a finite or infinite extended real number $L$, then $$\lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}, n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = L$$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 the OP wanted to show $\mathbb{R}$ in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Saad try \mathbb {R} in between the dollar signs. Produces $\mathbb {R}$.

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but maybe interesting nonetheless: there there is also a "discrete version" of L'hopital's theorem for functions defined only on $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose $f, g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=+\infty$. Then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{f(x+1)-f(x)\over g(x+1)-g(x)}$$ (assuming said limits exist of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is yes. More generally, there is an "equivalence" between limits of functions and limits of sequences. In particular, the following is a theorem:

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L \text { if and only if  for every sequence } \{x_n\} \text{ the following is true:}$$ $$ \text { if } \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = a \text{ then } \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)= L$$

Here we actually require $x_n \neq a$. This still holds true when $a,L \in \{\pm \infty\}$

EDIT- Just in the interests of being tedious, I should mention that we have to restrict $x_n$ to be in some open interval containing $a$ (or having $a$ as an endpoint if $a = \pm \infty$) on which $f$ is defined.